# ordering a table after removing certain keys

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a loop like:

```
for i = 1, 50 do
```

to make a box grid, and then I check aTable[ i ] if the value is not empty, if it's not, I put something in the box.

the problem is that, before running this loop, I loop through aTable and if the value is X, I do:

```
anotherTable[ i ] = anotherTable[ i ] + 1;
aTable[ i ] = nil;
```

so the problem with this is that my aTable could look like:

```
1:
        1   =   y
2:
        1   =   y
3:
        1   =   y
4:
        1   =   y
5:
        1   =   y
6:
        1   =   z
16:
        1   =   y
```

so here the keys 7-15 had value X.

How should I move them down so 16 becomes 7?

Comment: Instead of doing `aTable[i] = nil` do `table.remove(aTable, i)`.

Comment: does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I just made a third table, loop through aTable, check if value isn't nil, insert into third table